# What does "monotonously increasing" mean?

Tags: functions

> For a cubic function $f(x)=x^3-3ax^2+3bx-2$ 
>  Assume that $a=b$. If the function f(x) is monotonously increasing, then $?\leq a\leq?$

Could somebody explain what does the exercise is telling me to look for?

Comment: The function $f$ looks different depending on the value of $a$. The question is asking you to find the values of $a$ that make $f$ a monotonously increasing function, i.e. $f(x) < f(y)$ whenever $x < y$.

Comment: In the phrase, “Monotonously increasing”, the word monotonously is redundant, as “monotonous” means “either increasing or decreasing”.

Comment: Some writers use words like those to mean $x<y\implies f(x)≤f(y)$.  What people used to call "non-decreasing".  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) for instance.Those writers would then say "strictly increasing" to indicate that $x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)$.  It's not clear to me which use you intend.  To be sure, in your specific case, the distinction doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 2):

First:  Always pare your question to the minimum necessary.  Given that you demand $a = b$, there is no need to include $b$.  Just state your polynomial as $x^3 - 3 a x^2 + a x - 2$.  See?

Different values of $a$ give the following curves:

[image]

You are asked to find the range of values for $a$ in which the curve is non-decreasing everywhere.

Hint:  take the derivative of your function (it will depend upon $a$).  Then solve for the values of $a$ that ensure $\frac{d f(x)}{dx} \geq 0$ for all $x$.

Clear?

Hint:  The solution is $0 \leq a \leq 1$.  See if you can derive it!

Answer (score 2):

"Monotonous" means "repetitive or seemingly endless, and tedious or boring". The correct term is monotonic, or monotonically.

A function $f$ is increasing if $x<x'\implies f(x)\le f(x')$ whenever $x,x'$ are in the domain of $f$.

A function $f$ is decreasing if $x<x'\implies f(x)\ge f(x')$ whenever $x,x'$ are in the domain of $f$.

$f$ is strictly increasing if $x<x'\implies f(x)< f(x')$ whenever $x,x'$ are in the domain of $f$.

$f$ is strictly decreasing if $x<x'\implies f(x)> f(x')$ whenever $x,x'$ are in the domain of $f$.

$f$ is monotonic if $f$ is increasing or if $f$ is decreasing.

$f$ is strictly monotonic if $f$ is strictly increasing or if $f$ is strictly decreasing.

CAUTION: Not all texts adhere to this. Some assume "increasing" and "decreasing" and "monotonic" mean "strictly increasing" and "strictly decreasing" and "strictly monotonic".

SOLUTION.

$f(x)=x^3-3ax^2+3ax-2$ is increasing iff $0\le f'(x)=3x^2-6ax+3a=3((x-a)^2+a-a^2)$ for every $x$ iff $a-a^2\ge 0$ iff $0\le a\le 1.$